# Multitouch in android

Tags: android, touch, screen, multi-touch

I haved read:

> ACTION_DOWN is called when the user’s first finger reaches the screen.
>   ACTION_POINTER_DOWN is called when the user touches the screen with a second, third non-primary-finger.
>   When the user’s non primary finger leave the screen, ACTION_POINTER_UP is called.
>   At the time when the last finger leave the screen the ACTION_UP is called.

So how can I detect user’s primary finger leave the screen.

Comment: The last sentance says it all.  ACTION_UP.

Comment: last finger leave the screen the ACTION_UP is called. but user’s primary finger leave the screen isn't the last finger :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use this below example, it is best example for multitouch in Android

https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/MultitouchWithDynamicAddandRemove